# robots.txt file for multi language website

Tags: web-crawler, multilingual, robots.txt

hi I'm trying to generate a robots.txt file for my website but I'm having an issue dealing with multi language URL.
I want to disallow this URL for instance

```
http://www.example.com/en/shop
http://www.example.com/ar/shop
http://www.example.com/fr/shop
```

so do I have to write

```
Disallow: /en/shop
Disallow: /ar/shop
Disallow: /fr/shop
```

or this is enough ?

```
Disallow: /*/shop
```

thank you